# Cannot get Apache to find PDO driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, apache-http-server, mysql, php

I am using Windows 10 and have installed Apache2.4, PHP7.2 and MySQL. I am having trouble installing the driver for pdo_mysql

I have edited my php.ini file, and in the extensions section I have:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

I have also set the extension_dir directive to:

```
"C:\php72\ext"
```

In the command console I enter "php -m" and I can see PDO and pdo_mysql both listed.

[image: command console screenshot showing php -m]

I have restarted Apache but when I run a .php file including either `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` or `phpinfo();`
I can see that I do not have any drivers installed for PDO.

In my httpd.conf file I have

```
PHPIniDir “C:\php72\”
```

I have tried changing this to use forward and backslashes, and including and removing the trailing slash, restarting Apache after each change. I still cannot get the pdo_mysql driver to load.

It seems to me that the problem is with Apache not with PHP (as the pdo_mysql module appears when I run php -m in the command console), but I don't understand what I have done wrong. I searched for other people having the same problem but the solution always seemed to be the PHPIniDir, which I think I have set correctly.

The machine I am using was already running IIS so I have Apache listening to port 8090, rather than the default. I am not sure if this is relevant or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `PHPIniDir` is in the file `httpd-xampp.conf` in your apache installation folder, perhaps `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`, and the line should look something like `<IfModule php7_module> PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php" </IfModule>`.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't use xampp to install, so I don't have a C:\xampp directory, and I don't have a httpd-xampp.conf file either.

Comment: My PHPIniDir did not appear inside the IfModule tag as you suggested. I tried wrapping it inside those tags and restarting Apache, but the driver is still not loading. `<IfModule php7_module>
PHPIniDir “C:/php72/”
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php7_module "C:\php72\php7apache2_4.dll"
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled Apache service, deleted C:\Apache24 and installed from scratch, the  followed the steps to install pdo_mysql as before which has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, where modules were loaded when running via cli, but not when running same php config via Apache.

In my case the solution was to set the `extension_dir` in the php.ini file to the absolute path of modules folder (C:\php80\ext in my case).

Now both cli and Apache are loading the modules correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me the stupid instructions I was following to setup Fast CGI with Apache had me put the exe file where the ini file was supposed to go.

```
# Where is your php.ini file?
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/Program Files/php/php.exe" // should be ini
```

I changed that to the ini and it worked. I'm surprised php let me set php.exe as the ini file...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).